# NSXMLParser crash in xmlFindCharEncodingHandler

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsxmlparser, libxml2

An iOS app that has been parsing the same XML feed for about the last year and a half has suddenly developed an intermittent crash inside `[NSXMLParser parse]`. Crash logs indicate I instantiate an `NSData` object from a URL and then use `[NSXMLParser initWithData:]` to create my parser. A snippet of the stack trace follows:

```
0   libxml2.2.dylib                 0x366eb1fc xmlFindCharEncodingHandler + 124
1   libxml2.2.dylib                 0x366f0f84 xmlParseEncodingDecl + 416
2   libxml2.2.dylib                 0x366f2ed8 xmlParseXMLDecl + 304
3   libxml2.2.dylib                 0x366fb688 xmlParseChunk + 808
4   Foundation                      0x32753d5e -[NSXMLParser parse] + 198
```

The crash reported is

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000
```

I should also note that I am performing the parse and the download in the background inside an `NSOperation`'s `main` method.

Has anyone ever encountered such a crash, and if so have any tips on how to resolve? I have already reached out to the maintainers of the XML feeds to ask if there is any issues with their character encoding, but they indicate no changes have been made.